# Sharepoint Library "Name" column not visible in calculated-column dropdown list

Tags: sharepoint, calculated-columns, calculated-field

In Modern Sharepoint I created a Document Library by New>Document Library and then uploading *.png files.
They are stored in a Column Name called Name (linked to document with edit menu). This can be seen in Settings>Edit View

Now I want to create a Calculated Column to calculate the last character before the .png in the filename which are in the Name Column.
I go to Add Column > More > Create Column and define Column Name and Type.

Then defining the formula but the Name column **does not appear** in the drop down list.

Any suggestions ?
thx

Answer (score 0):

It's known case. We cannot use filename in calculated field. You could vote here: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/36029680-use-filename-in-calculated-field

As a workaround, you could use workflow /flow to make the Title field gets the filename. Then use title field in the calculated column.

Comment: Unfortunately, the UserVoice is closed and there seems to still be no easy way to use the filename in calculated column.